# Is it possible to transfer files from one web server to another without downloading and uploading?

Tags: linux, web-server, web-hosting

I want to move my files form one web server to another, but I think its a double task to  download them and again upload to another one. I was looking for any PHP script or something. Any method that doesn't involve this double traffic process.

Comment: Hi Santosh. This question is much too open-ended for ServerFault. I'd suggest reading through the FAQ. And also reading through and writing your questions with this post in mind: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault.

Comment: Your question doesn't appear to be on topic at Server Fault, as you do not seem to be the server administrator of either server. In this case, you may do better at our sister site [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). When you go, be sure to add additional details about the web hosting providers you are using, such as OS, control panels, and any other information that may help others understand your environment and answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

If you have shell access on both machines, you can simply login to one machine and use `scp` or `rsync` to transfer the files directly.

Comment: If no shell access?

Comment: @SantoshKumar If you don't have shell access, then you're asking at the wrong Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is known as [File eXchange Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol) (FXP), if you have ftp access to both the server it is simple and easy, [here](http://www.flashfxp.com/forum/flashfxp/faq/14656-site-site-transfers-fxp.html) is a good read and a good client also.